# smarty conditional {block} in html not working

Tags: html, smarty

I'm implementing a conditional `{block}` tag implementation with parent-child html using smarty.

In my parent I have :

```
<li class="{block name=block1}{/block}" style="{block name=block2}{/block}">
```

In child html:

```
{if $value}
    {block name=block2}background-color: {$value}{/block}
{else}
    {block name=block1}selected{/block}
{/if}
```

Expectation : based on the value of $value any one of if conditional block should execute and fill the parents `<li>`

whats happening : it is executing both whether `$value` is non blank or blank and filling both `class` and `style` attribute.

Please help what I am doing wrong here or my implementation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if $value}
    {block name=block2}background-color: {$value}{/block}
{else}
    {block name=block1}selected{/block}
{/if}
```

at least /if should used to close the tag of if

Comment: apology for the typo. i am closing the if correctly in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty `{blocks}` cannot be used with `{if}` conditionals. They will always be executed. See here a [Post in the smarty forum](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=64132) where it is explained somewhat better and is given an (ugly, in my opinion) workaround at the bottom.

Bottom line is, you can't easily achieve what you're trying to do, you will have to change your code.